# Meet llvm-config problem compiling by clang when following llvm tutorial

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, llvm-config

I am now learning `llvm` for coursework in school. I followed the llvm official tutorial and met a problem when finishing character 3 (link: https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html).

Below is my environment:

```
Windows 10 with AMD R5800H
clang version 16.0.0
LLVM version 16.0.0 
CMake version 3.25.0
clang and LLVM were built by source code from GitHub using CMake and VS-2022
```

These are the files I include in my .cc program:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/APFloat.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

We can see that the first few lines include the llvm header files.

When I finished coding, I tried to compile in the PowerShell statement below (*PS*. I don't know what each part means, just following the tutorial):

```bash
clang++ -g -O3 my-lang.cc `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o mylang
```

But the Shell outputs the following information:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--cxxflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--ldflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--system-libs'
clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'core -o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'mylang'
```

It is obvious that there is something wrong with my clang and/or llvm-config, but I failed to solve them.

- The first way I tried is to reinstall the clang and llvm to my computer, while it did not make sense obviously.
- Then I tried to run statement in the Command Line (CMD). But it has another similar but different output.

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--cxxflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--ldflags'
clang: error: unsupported option '--system-libs'
clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '`llvm-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'core`'
```

- After that I verified whether it can works for clang and llvm-config separately.

I only do `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` and get things below:

```
-IE:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\llvm\include -IE:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\include -std:c++17   /EHs-c- /GR- -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-LIBPATH:E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib
E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMCore.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMRemarks.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMBitstreamReader.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMBinaryFormat.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMSupport.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMDemangle.lib
psapi.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib
```

And do `clang++ my-lang.cc -o mylang` and get things below:

```
my-lang.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/APFloat.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ADT/APFloat.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I think these are files that I need to link in my program, and these also proves that `llvm-config` can works properly.

But why clang and llvm-config cannot work properly together?

How can I compile my program?

==========

edit date: 2022/12/2

Yeah. I tried `$()` and it did work. But a new error has occorred.
When I do the statement `clang++ -g -O3 my-lang.cc $(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core) -o mylang` in the Power Shell, it said:

```
clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMCore.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMRemarks.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMBitstreamReader.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMBinaryFormat.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMSupport.lib E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\LLVMDemangle.lib'
clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'psapi.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib'
```

The first point I am really confused about is that those files exist on my PC and are on the right path.

```
PS E:\CDemo\llvm\llvm-project\build\Release\lib> dir
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
...
-a----         2022/12/1     22:59       19281400 LLVMCore.lib
-a----         2022/12/1     22:58        1184306 LLVMRemarks.lib
-a----         2022/12/1     22:56         240648 LLVMBitstreamReader.lib
-a----         2022/12/1     22:56         887888 LLVMBinaryFormat.lib
-a----         2022/12/1     22:56       11201768 LLVMSupport.lib
-a----         2022/12/1     22:56         862826 LLVMDemangle.lib
...
```

Second is what these mean `psapi.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib` and where can I find them?

Comment: Those \`\` quotes are used in Bash to launch a subcommand in a command. AFAIK these quotes are not supported by Powershell. However, you can use `$()` instead. Try with `clang++ -g -O3 my-lang.cc $(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core) -o mylang` instead.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. `$()` works but a new error has occurred.

Comment: `psapi.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib` are Windows SDK libraries. You can install them using Visual Studio's installer for example. For the files not found, I think it might be due string escaping.

Comment: I know this is not the reply that you want, but since this is for coursework I guess you have a tight schedule to get this up and running; so here is my suggestion: Building LLVM under Linux is much more friendly than on Windows (and the generated LLVM-IR for a regular C application is also simpler). You could try the Windows Subsystem for Linux for your coursework to allow you to move faster (I personally work using WSL).

Comment: Yeah. I run my program successfully within WSL. It is really convenient.